# Overlapping Records in t_package, t_object, t_connector

Tags: primary-key, enterprise-architect

A package is also a model element. Therefore, there are Package records in t_object.

What is the primary key field that relates `t_package` and `t_object`?

```
Select * from t_package  
inner join t_object
on t_package.? = t_object.?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both have the same `ea_guid`, but the `t_object.pdata1`  also corresponds with the `t_Package.Package_ID`.

Comment: While one Sparxian brought the ea_guid wisdom to his believing user community, another Sparxian told us that this is very unofficial for good (but only know to him) reasons. Not sure about `pdata1`.  I guess this is one I figured out by myself but there was never any Sparxian's word against that. It might as well be that this is documented through MiscData(0).

Comment: Pdata/MiscData is definitely correct, and in general I prefer that route to the guids because most structural relationships (package/element parents, connector source/targets) use the numeric identifier. But then other relationships are guid-based, so which is neatest does depend on the situation.